# How to change the type of a column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have a table in SQL SERVER that has several columns. One of this column had type: `VARCHAR(1000)`. But I want to change it to `VARCHAR(MAX)`.
How to I do this with execute a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

You just need to do the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) statement in sql server

```
alter table <table> alter column col_name varchar(max)
```

Optionally you could give NULL/NOT NULL, DEFAULT etc.. along with the alter statement itself

[See this link for more examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Do Something like This

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] VARCHAR(MAX)
```

But I prefer using fixed size in a column Instead of MAX Because It takes more memory and Hence somehow reduces the speed.